# replacing placeholder with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, placeholder

I am creating a solution to the `placeholder` issue to make it work in every browser using only jquery.

Its working good up until now...
This is how far i've come

```
var formId = ["Name", "E-mail", "Subject", "Message"];
$.each(formId, function(i) {
    $("input, textarea").focus(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === formId[i])
            $(this).val("");
    }).focusout(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "")
            $(this).val(formId[i]);
    });
});
```

Its working perfectly up until the focus out part. When i focus out the input field, it repopulates the value with `Name` in every input field.. Have tried my way with different solutions but this is as close i've gotten.. Any one got any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be the best way to tackle this problem.  I saw a solution like the following on a blog before.  You add the placeholder attribute to the inputs, so they will work on modern browsers, and you add jQuery to inputs with placeholder attributes, like `[placeholder]`:

```
$('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.val('');
    input.removeClass('placeholder');
  }
}).blur(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.addClass('placeholder');
    input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
  }
}).blur();

$('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
      input.val('');
    }
  })
});
```

I can't find the blog right now, which is a shame, because this code, I believe, is completely copied from that site and works great, cross-browser.

**How this works, and why this is a better approach:**

Instead of putting handlers on every input and textarea element, you can easily filter exactly which ones should have handlers on them: those that have a placeholder attribute.

A `.submit()` handler will keep the default text from being posted as values.

Maybe I should speak on what I feel are problems with your code:

You're using an each function to call multiple focus handlers, which are quite similar.  You probably don't need the each function.  You could just use $('input, textarea').focus() because that will add a handler to each input.  Then, you could check if `$.inArray($(this).val(),formId)`.  Docs for [inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

Comment: this works with some mods! one thing that doesnt work in IE tho with this is the `reset` button, i would like that to work aswell. Else it works perfectly!

Comment: To just make it work in IE and use placeholder as it is in other browsers, that supports it, I used `if ($.browser.msie) { code-above }` hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

forget about `var formId`, instead add an attribute data-placeholder in your input/textarea html tag with the appropriate values, then :

```
 $("input, textarea").on({
    focus : function() {
      var $t=$(this);
      if ($t.val() ===$t.data("placeholder"))
        $t.val("");
    }, 
    blur : function() {
      var $t=$(this);
      if ($t.val() === "")
        $t.val($t.data("placeholder"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Since OP is working with placeholders, I think this could be done with the placeholder attribute instead of data-default.

Comment: which doesn't make much difference ! but i should have put data-placeholder in fact; nb: the way you bind events belongs to the past !

Comment: this works in all browser EXCEPT ie with is the point... I could use placeholder. The `default-value` doesn't work in ie.